# Selenium send_keys ignores space

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write a name into an input field, but it seems to ignore the space between the first and last name, which is quite important in this instance. Have anybody else experienced similar problems? I'm running the script locally on a Firefox browser (33.1.1) on a Mac.

My code:

```
#write given message to element specified by name
def write_to_input(self,name,message):
    inputEl = self.driver.find_element_by_name(name)
    inputEl.send_keys(message)

#writing name
self.write_to_input("name","John Doe")
```

Comment: ALthough I don't like the "trial and error" approach when answering here, try, in this case, escaping the space with a "\"  character. (Remember to escape the "\" itself in the Python script - i.e.: `slef.write_to_input("name","John\\ Doe")`

Comment: @jsbueno it just adds a blackslash i.e "John\Doe" :(

Comment: I switched to chrome instead and not there is no problem. I'm not sure why firefox doesn't accept the spaces